# ASCII table and String

Tags: c#, .net

Trying to build string by using ASCII table. I was expecting to get black square located in 219 position, but got character `U`. Why?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string d = "";
    d += (char)219;
    Console.WriteLine(d);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Because it's not ASCII, it's UTF16, and [in UTF16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Basic_Latin) the character with code 219 is `Û`.

Comment: Perhaps it's time to understand that people teach ASCII because they believe learning a simpiler thing is a good first step. Sort of like the Bohr model of the atom in teaching Chemistry. The difference is, though, the Bohr model is useful for certain predictions. ASCII is simply the wrong thing. With character encodings you are using exactly one. In text data types for .NET, JavaScript, Java, VB4/5//6/A/Script, …, that is UTF-16. UTF-16 is a character encoding for the Unicode character set. When people say ASCII, ask them which standard or specification says it applies in the particular case.

Answer (score 2):

`(char)219;` isn't convert to `ASCII`.

If you want to let the number be `ASCII`, you can try to use `Encoding.ASCII.GetString` to get `ASCII` value.

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[]{127});
```

**NOTE**

`Encoding.ASCII` does not provide error detection. Any byte greater than 127 is decoded as the Unicode question mark `?`.

Comment: You can get any of the built-in encodings configured for exceptions instead of replacement. `Encoding.GetEncoding("US-ASCCI", EncoderFallback.ExceptionFallback, DecoderFallback.ExceptionFallback).GetString(new byte[] { 219 })`

Answer (score 2):

ASCII is a 7 bit encoding and does neither contain a black square, nor does it contain a character with value 219 (the highest ASCII value is 127).
To get a black square, you can use a Unicode literal:

```
d += (char)'\u25A0';
```

See https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=black+square for the Unicode character and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/char for the Unicode literal syntax.